# Finding a $f(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}a_k x^{4k+2}$ such that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions

To provide a little context for this question, I recently proved that for a suitable function $f(x)$ the following identity holds

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f'(k)=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f'(n)}{e^{2\pi n}-1}$$

The criteria for suitability of the function $f(x)$ essentially comes down to two major factors.  Firstly, $f(x)$ must possess a power series expansion of the form

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k x^{4k+2}$$

such the series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\vert{a_k}\vert}{(2\pi)^{4k}}(4k+2)! < \infty$$

Secondly, we must have $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

After proving this, I wanted to find a specific example so that I could compute both of the series to ensure the identity actually holds and I didn't just make some error in my proof.  I didn't think this would be too difficult of a task, but frustratingly I have not been able to come up with a single example!

My first thought was to try something Bessel-like as $J_v(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.  Along these lines I figured the most sensible function to start with was the Wright function $z^2\phi(4,3,-z^4)$ where

$$\phi(\alpha,\beta,z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!\Gamma(\alpha n + \beta)}$$

so that

$$z^2\phi(4,3,-z^4) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(4n+2)!}z^{4n+2}$$

Unfortunately, I quickly became aware of the fact that the asymptotics of more general hypergeometric functions can become quite complicated.  More specifically to my needs, $z^2\phi(4,3,-z^4)$ does not go to $0$ as $z \to \infty$. This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0701069.pdf) gives the asymptotics for the Wright function.

I am wondering, does anyone have any suggestions on constructing a function with my desired properties?  Or showing that such a function does indeed exist?

Comment: Just a note: the example $$x^2e^{-x^4}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} x^{4n+2}$$ has the desired limit but does not satisfy the other property (the sum very much does not converge).

Comment: Perhaps find a suitable $a_k$ that would give you the $f(x)$? If you let $a_k = \frac{1}{(4k+2)!}, You'll get a known series, and thus an $f$. Does this help at all?

Comment: granted, if you choose that as your sequence, you'll have to consider $f(\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: @Carl Schildkraut Yea I noticed that as well. Every function I came up with had one property or the other, but not both.

Comment: @Ryan Goulden. I looked at that as well. It can be given in terms of Sin and Sinh.  Unfortunately it doesn't go to zero as z goes to infnity... :(

Comment: @FofX indeed. That was why I suggested to observe $f(\frac{1}{x})$, that away it vanishes at infinity. But the issue that comes there, then, is that it isn't defined at $k=0$

Comment: @mathworker21 Not that I know of, unless I am missing something. For instance if we let $f(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^{4k+2}}{(4k+2)!}$ then the associated series converges as it is just the geometric series.  On the other hand $f(x)=1/2(-x^2-\cos(x)-\cosh(x))$ which clearly does not go to 0 in the limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's straightforward to check that such function $f$ is entire, has [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type) less or equal to 1 and is of [exponential type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_type), i.e. satisfy the estimate $|f(z)|\le C e^{c|z|}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Since $f(i z)=-f(z)$ function $f$ also tends to zero on the imaginary axis as $|z|\to \infty$.

Consider $f$ in the angle $A=\{0<\arg z<\pi/2\}$. The function is bounded on its sides and grows no faster than exponentially inside. Applying the [Phragmén–Lindelöf principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle#Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle_for_a_sector_in_the_complex_plane) one gets that $f$ is bounded in $A$. By the same argument $f$ is bounded on the entire plane and therefore is a constant. From the condition at the infinity it follows  that $f(z)\equiv0$.